# Diagonal Dataframe to 1 row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to convert a diagonal Dataframe to 1 row Dataframe.
Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[7, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 2, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 3, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 8],],
                  columns=list('ABCD'))
   A  B  C  D
0  7  0  0  0
1  0  2  0  0
2  0  0  3  0
3  0  0  0  8
```

Expected output:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  7  2  3  8
```

what i tried so far to do this:

```
df1 = df.sum().to_frame().transpose()
df1
   A  B  C  D
0  7  2  3  8
```

It does the job. But is there any elegant way to do this by `groupby` or some other `pandas` builtin?

Comment: What you have is pretty elegant. You might want to replace `.transpose()` with just `.T`, like this: `df.sum().to_frame().T`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is any other 'elegant' way, I can only propose alternatives:

Use [numpy.diagonal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html)

```
pd.DataFrame([df.to_numpy().diagonal()], columns=df.columns)

    A   B   C   D
0   7   2   3   8
```

Use groupby with boolean (not sure if this is better than your solution):

```
df.groupby([True] * len(df), as_index=False).sum()


    A   B   C   D
0   7   2   3   8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `np.diagonal(df)`:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.diagonal(df), df.columns).T

    A   B   C   D
0   7   2   3   8
```